# Unresolved supertypes: kotlinx.parcelize.Parceler

Tags: android, parcelable

I'm trying to migrate from `kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize` to `kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize` but I'm getting following issue while doing so:

**Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
class com.myapp.models.Text.Raw.Companion, unresolved supertypes: kotlinx.parcelize.Parceler**

This is the source:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Parcel
import android.os.Parcelable
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parceler
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize

sealed class Text : Parcelable {

    @Parcelize
    data class Raw(private val text: CharSequence) : Text() {

        override fun resolveToCharSequence(context: Context): CharSequence = text

        companion object : Parceler<Raw> {

            override fun create(parcel: Parcel): Raw {
                return Raw(checkNotNull(parcel.readString()))
            }

            override fun Raw.write(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
                parcel.writeString(text.toString())
            }
        }
    }
    ... 
}
```

After changes:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Parcel
import android.os.Parcelable
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parceler
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize

sealed class Text : Parcelable {

    @Parcelize
    data class Raw(private val text: CharSequence) : Text() {

        override fun resolveToCharSequence(context: Context): CharSequence = text

        companion object : Parceler<Raw> {

            override fun create(parcel: Parcel): Raw {
                return Raw(checkNotNull(parcel.readString()))
            }

            override fun Raw.write(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
                parcel.writeString(text.toString())
            }
        }
    }
    ... 
}
```

**build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {    
    com.android.library
    `kotlin-android`
    `kotlin-parcelize`
    `kotlin-kapt`
}
...
```

If I remove the companion object part there is no error.

And idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

> If I remove the companion object part there is no error.

> And idea what the problem could be?

My guess would be the companion object part :)

The whole point of `Parcelize` is that you don't need to manually code the parceling logic. You're not doing anything special in the companion objects - just delete them.

Comment: Yeah, it's legacy code, I don't have idea why they added that one.